# Regex to match on a word but only if it isn't preceded or followed by another specific word

Tags: regex, exchange-server, regex-lookarounds

Need a Regex string to work with custom Exchange DLP "Sensitive Information" type.

i.e match on Smith but not if  John Smith or Smith John

`(?i)(?&lt;!John\s)Smith`   appears to work for "John Smith" though I'm not convinced it is 100% efficient.

`(?i)(Smith.*\s(?!John))` appears to work for "Smith John" but not if followed by a space or new line.

Have tried the following to combine them into one string but it doesn't seem to work at all.

`(?i)(?&lt;!John\s)Smith |(?i)(Smith.*\s(?!John))`

`(?i)(?&lt;!John\s)Smith.*\s(?!John)`

What schoolboy error am I making?

Comment: Use `(?i)(?<!John\s)Smith(?!\s+John)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zM0BiI/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`(?i)(?<!John\s)Smith |(?i)(Smith.*\s(?!John))`](https://regex101.com/r/zM0BiI/2) pattern is matching `Smith` that does not have `John`+ 1 whitespace before it, OR a `Smith` that is followed with any amount of chars followed with a whitespace that is not immediately followed with `John`. Thus, it matches `Smith` in a lot of positions.

The [`(?i)(?<!John\s)Smith.*\s(?!John)`](https://regex101.com/r/zM0BiI/3) pattern grabs a `Smith` that is not immediately preceded with `John` + whitespace, and all text up to the final whitespace that is not immediately followed with `John`.

Make sure the `\s` pattern is inside the lookahead:

```
(?i)(?<!John\s)Smith(?!\s+John)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zM0BiI/1)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive inline modifier
- `(?<!John\s)` - a location that is not immediately preceded with `Hohn` and a whitespace char
- `Smith` - a literal substring
- `(?!\s+John)` - the `Smith` substring should not be immediately followed with 1+ whitespaces (or if you use `\s*`, with 0+ whitespaces) and the substring `John`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.